# Display multiple bar on barChart from a custom reducer

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a group with custom reducer calculating various total and average values. The goal is to show them all on the same barChart. But I can only get the first bar to show. Here is the JSFiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/71k0guxe/15/

Is it possible to show all the value on the barChart?

Thanks in advance!

Data

```
ID,SurveySent,ResponseReceived
1,Yes,No
2,No,No
3,Yes,Yes
4,No,No
5,Yes,Yes
6,No,No
7,Yes,No
8,No,No
9,Yes,No
10,No,No
```

Code

```
var chart = dc.barChart("#test");
//d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, experiments) {
var experiments = d3.csvParse(d3.select('pre#data').text());

  var ndx                 = crossfilter(experiments),
      dimStat        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "Statistics";}),
      groupStat       = dimStat.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  ++p.count;
  if (v.SurveySent === "Yes") p.sent++;
  if (v.ResponseReceived === "Yes") p.received++;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  --p.count;
  if (v.SurveySent === "Yes") p.sent--;
  if (v.ResponseReceived === "Yes") p.received--;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {count: 0, sent: 0, received: 0};
}

  chart
    .width(400)
    .height(400)
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .label(function(d) { return d.data.value })
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["Total", "Sent", "Received"]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
    .dimension(dimStat)
    .group(groupStat)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) { 
           //Is it possible to return count sent and received all from here?
            return d.value.count;
      })
    .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function(d) {
            console.log("click!", d);
        });
    });
    chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got some idea from the FAQ section of dc.js/wiki/FAQ
Fake Groups
"dc.js uses a very limited part of the crossfilter API - in fact, it really only uses dimension.filter() and group.all()."
I don't care about filtering, so i just need to mark up my own group.all. Basically transpose it from one row to multiple row. Works my purpose.

```
/* solution */
var groupStatTranposed = group_transpose(groupStat);

function group_transpose(source_group, f) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return [
                {key: "Total", value: source_group.all()[0].value.count},
                {key: "Sent", value: source_group.all()[0].value.sent},
                {key: "Received", value: source_group.all()[0].value.received}
            ];           
        }
    };
}
//use  groupStatTranposed in the chart.
/** solution */
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. This is the solution I'd recommend. To clarify, this will work fine for reacting to filters on other charts. One would need to define [filterHandler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor) in order to get this chart to filter anything else, because now the keys are different from those used by the dimension. (This is not always possible.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon! You are totally right.  I can't filter on it. Another way to do it is to follow the example at http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/table-on-aggregated-data.html. I haven't tried that out though.